# Convert Hex Number into 2 Byte String Notation in C#

Tags: c#, hex, byte

I am looking for the simplest way to achieve this :

num = 2376.75 => 0949 ( hex conversion of rounded off of 2376.5 to 2377).Num could be negative num ber as well.

I have very ugly code to do this which luckily works for me :

```
 val1 = 2376.75
    int val = Convert.ToInt16( Math.Round(val1));
    valStringLsb = ((byte)val ).ToString("X");
     if (valStringLsb.Length == 1)
    {

      valStringLsb = "0" + valStringLsb;
    }

    string valStringmsb = ((byte)(si >> 8)).ToString("X");
    int k = valStringmsb.Length;
    if (k == 1)
    {
       valStringmsb = "0" + valStringmsb;
    }
    else
    {

    valStringmsb = ((byte)(val >> 8)).ToString("X").Equals("0") ? "00" : (((byte)(val >> 8)).ToString("X")); 
    }

    valString += (valStringLsb + valStringmsb);
```

Is there any simple way or API to achieve this?
The reason i want to do this is I want 0949 value not 949 value for 2377.

Comment: you mean string str = val.ToString("X2"), well it throws an excpetion : {"Format specifier was invalid."}

Comment: `((int)Math.Round(num)).ToString("X4");`

Comment: @L.B works fine for positive numbers , but not for negative numbers.

Comment: @Raulp A sample negative number + expected hex number?

Comment: yes for negative number it should show somethinf like FFXX..instead of FFFFFFXX

Comment: @Raulp then just replace `(int)` with `(short)` which is a 16 bit number.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have simplicity you could use this:

```
Func<int, string> DecimalToHex = new Func<int, string>((input) => 
{
    return Convert.ToString(input, 16).PadLeft(4, '0');
});
```

The important part is the `Convert` so you don't have to use a `Func<>` method. If you want to use this approach, then you will have to supply your rounded number. You can not supply a double into this function directly.

Comment: I know, but if you performed your round function and then inserted into this function. Isn't that what the question stated?